# How to implement real-time voice feature in Stand alone Android Wear Application?

Tags: wear-os, sip, voip, voip-android, android-wear-3.0

We already have a standalone Android watch application, and we intend implement real-time voice calls using SIP and VOIP protocol. According to my real-time research, voice calls using VOIP can be implemented in conjunction with phone and watch apps.
Is there a way to integrate real-time audio calls into an independent Android Watch app?

Please let me know if anyone has added a voice call capability to an application.